# Wet venting of added bathroom sketch -question is this layout OK?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, venting

I am adding a master bathroom shower, toilet and double vanity to an abutting wall of a full bathroom, Is this wet venting good if I tie into existing 2" shower vent in the shared wall?[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but I'm guessing you'll have venting problems there. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

Found this at [https://inspectapedia.com/](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Plumbing-Vent-Distance-Codes.php#VDist)  Which references Maryland plumbing codes.  You should check your local code for what's appropriate in your situation.

The second table, which shows trap-vent distances says that for a 2" trap (shower) the maximum distance to the vent is 5 feet.  You're way over.  It also specifies a minimum vent size of 3"